# JSON Schema: Additional properties false for embedded objects

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a json schema with hundreds of objects, each containing other objects and so on...

I want all my json schema objects to have the option "additionalProperties" set to false, but it seems that I have to set it for each object in the json schema.

Is there any solution like setting "additionalProperties" to false only once for all objects including multiple level of embedded objects in the whole schema ?

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"description": "Modified JSON Schema draft v4 that includes the optional '$ref' and 'format'",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "id": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "box": {
        "type": "object",
         "properties": {
            "anotherBox": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Do you have an example json?

Comment: Yes, I edited my comment.
The idea is to prevent from having additional properties in each object without having to set the "additionalProperties" in each child object

Comment: @bobier2 that's not possible, it's possible in one way if the entities in all the levels follow same structure